# Windows phone 8 application sharing

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there any way to share an application to a customer for a review? I need to do it without publishing to the market.

Comment: like beta testing the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way how you would typically do this is either publishing a beta app or a hidden app to the Windows Phone Store. However, your app has to pass certification. If the customer has access to a developer-unlocked phone or uses company app distribution, you don't have to incorporate the Windows Phone Store.

**Beta app submission:** Your app is submitted to the Windows Phone Store, but is only visible for users that are explicitly whitelisted by you (using Microsoft Accounts). [(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

**Hidden app submission:** Your app is submitted to the Windows Phone Store, but is only visible for users that have the link. It's not visible through searching or browsing the Store. [(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj619160%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

**Developer-unlocked phone:** Your customer deploys a XAP package to his developer-unlocked phone using the Windows Phone App Deployment Tool.

**Company App Distribution:** If your customer uses Company App Distribution, you could deploy the app using the customer's company store.

From my own experience, it's best to use a beta app submission since it's the easiest option and your app's compliance with the Windows Phone Store Guidelines is checked right off the bat.